# Was the medicine at the end acid?

Tags: curse-of-the-golden-flower

At the end of *Curse of the Golden Flower*, the Empress refuses to take the poisoned medicine that she's been having as of late and knocks the cup into the air, spilling the medicine onto the table.

However, we see that the spilled medicine starts to corrode the wood. does this mean it was actually acid? or was this some sort of symbolism?